# Processor strained, process CPU usage low, no activity in Filemon

Tags: process, logitech-mouse, file-monitoring

I have a 6 year old laptop with the following spec:

- Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600)
- Make and model: SAMSUNG 770Z5E/780Z5E
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3635QM CPU @ 2.40 GHz
- RAM: 8 GB

Of late there appears to be a process which is causing the laptop to get hot and make the fans whir like crazy. I've had this process and the software (Logitech mouse utility) for over 3 years. The only system changes have been Windows updates which I apply once a quarter. Nothing has been installed for over a year.

The processes is LogiOptionsMgr.exe. As soon as I kill it, the laptop settles down within 30 seconds. The strange thing is the process only claims to be using < 1% CPU and Filemon registers no IO (disk, registry, network etc).

Everything I'm seeing is against what I know about computers. If the process utilization is showing < 1% that should not be a cause for the laptop to behave like this. And in any case, the process does not seem to be doing anything according to Filemon. Again, kill it, and the laptop is back to normal.

What might be going on?

Comment: Does the program have any animations, video or 3D graphics running? Could be that it is using the graphics rather than CPU.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I just downloaded a GPU monitoring tool and can see that even whilst on the desktop with no games or video running, the GPU is maxing out, not the CPU! I will play around with the GPU settings to see what it might be.

Answer (score 3):

So after the direction from Mokubai, it turns out that AMD's Switchable Graphics software was misdetecting Logitech software as an an application that demanded my 3D graphics card to kick in with high performance settings.

My laptop has built in Intel graphics and also AMD Radeon 9700 series. I created application profiles within the AMD Catalyst Software to explicit treat all Logitech software as ones that try to optimize battery life over performance. Seems to have done it. This glitch has kicked in after a Windows update so don't know who to blame really.

Answer (score 1):

Even after migrating the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` to the iGPU, it will continue to consume a certain amount of watts. Below I'll show how to reduce the electricity bill by completely eliminating the problem.

**Note:** You are [not the only one with this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=logioptionsmgr+gpu+usage) [problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=logioptionsmgr+gpu+usage) ([more than 10,000 <sup>(approximately 34,557)</sup> people](https://whitelist.kaspersky.com/advisor#search/B56397B215E676C1234E8BEF23E38FC85513DD56) in total):

- [Why does `logioptionsmgr.exe` use up to 30% of my GPU <sup>NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti (200 Watt)</sup> while idle?](https://www.reddit.com/r/LogitechG/comments/mxcokw/why_does_logioptionsmgrexe_use_up_to_30_of_my_gpu/)

  - [Logitech Support: Logitech Options high GPU load](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360043928033-Logitech-Options-high-GPU-load) <sup>8% of NVIDIA GeForce RTX 20?0 Super</sup>
  - [Logitech Support: `LogiOptionsMgr.exe (UNICODE)` Gpu usage](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-ca/community/posts/360032777974-LogiOptionsMgr-exe-UNICODE-Gpu-usage) <sup>2‑3% of NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 (150 Watt)</sup>
- [Logitech Mouse Software using GPU power](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/5xj0hz/logitech_mouse_software_using_gpu_power/) <sup>5‑10% of NVIDIA GeForce 970 GTX (145 Watt)</sup>
- <del>[Anyone having problems with high cpu use with `Logioptions.exe` running?](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/68xu93/anyone_having_problems_with_high_cpu_use_with/)</del>
- [Logitech OPTIONS SOFTWARE IS eating up your GPU!!!!](https://forums.evga.com/Logitech-OPTIONS-SOFTWARE-IS-eating-up-your-GPU-m2740358.aspx) <sup>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 (150 Watt); T with `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` (idle, load): 53‑55°C, 82‑85°C; w/o: 40°C, 70°C.</sup> <sup>[21% of NVIDIA Titan Xp (250 Watt)](https://forums.evga.com/Logitech-OPTIONS-SOFTWARE-IS-eating-up-your-GPU-m2740358.aspx#msg2817079).</sup>
- [Logitech Software *Warning*](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/458604254424012441/) <sup>[T with `LCore.exe` (idle): 50°C; w/o: 30°C](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/458604254424012441/#c458604254424066685).</sup>

If I open [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io) and add the columns "GPU" and "GPU dedicated bytes", then in my case the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` utilizes 0.94% of the GPU (6.19% when moving any window) and 1.14 MB.

Now let's try to localize the problem (thread, call stack):

1. in Process Hacker: double click on `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` process > in Properties window: switch to Threads tab
2. sort ▼ by CPU column
3. try to suspend the thread that utilizes the most CPU: open the context menu of the thread > "Suspend" item
4. in main window of Process Hacker: the load on the GPU should disappear
   in Threads tab: the thread row has turned gray
5. now you can look at the call stack (double click on the thread) — in my case, the stack was like this:

   ```
   0, ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
   1, KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9c
   2, d3d9.dll!Direct3DCreate9+0x194fe
   3, d3d9.dll!Direct3DCreate9Ex+0x17df
   4, d3d9.dll!Direct3DCreate9Ex+0x1794
   5, d3d9.dll!Direct3DShaderValidatorCreate9+0x1515b
   6, d3d9.dll!Direct3DShaderValidatorCreate9+0x98aa
   7, d3d9.dll!Direct3DShaderValidatorCreate9+0x167c0
   8, d3d9.dll!DebugSetLevel+0x1584e
   9, LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0xd4343
   10, LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0x94947
   11, LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0x1d6184
   12, LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0x1dbae3
   13, LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0x1dbc8a
   14, kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
   15, ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
   ```

   **Note:** ignore the names of the `d3d9.dll` functions for now — they are inaccurate (you will see the correct names below).

Next, let's try to locate the problematic place (#9 in the call stack above) in the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` code and fix it ourselves. By the way, the version of my `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` is 3.20.35 <sup>[not](https://www.guru3d.com/news_story/vulnrebility_logitech_options_users_should_uninstall_immediately.html) [vulnerable](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1663)</sup>.

**Note:** remember that you have suspended one thread of `LogiOptionsMgr.exe`.

You will need the [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com) debugger. I hope you have experience with it, if not then here are a few settings that will make working with it easier (Options menu > Preferences):

- [Events](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/settings/Events.html) tab > "Break on" — unselect all of this (in the future, you can try to enable "Entry Breakpoint*" and "Attach Breakpoint")
- [Exceptions](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/settings/Exceptions.html) tab: "Add Range" button > start:`00000000`, end:`FFFFFFFF`

Let's begin:

1. File menu > [Attach](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/menus/File.html#attach): select `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` and Attach
2. load symbols for `d3d9.dll` (this is done only once):

   - in Symbols tab: left panel > "d3d9.dll" module > context menu: "Download Symbols for This Module"
3. find this place in the program code: `LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0xd4343` (#9 in the call stack above):

   1. switch to the thread you previously suspended — in Threads tab (x64dbg):

      1. find it by `1` in the "Suspend Count" column or by TID<sub>Process Hacker, dec</sub> → the "ID" column <sub>x64dbg, hex</sub>
      2. double click on it
   2. you are at the top of the stack — roll back a little:

      1. in Call Stack tab: context menu: "[Show suspected call stack frame](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/views/CallStack.html)"
      2. in Comment column: find the "return to logioptionsmgr.… from d3d9.…"
      3. double click on it
   3. in CPU tab: scroll up the [asm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) a little to see the previous instructions

      - the `test` instruction is currently selected (in my case — `test eax,eax`); above it is the `call` instruction (in my case — `call qword ptr ds:[rax+3C8]`)
   4. set a breakpoint on the `call` instruction — click on the • gray bullet on the left → it will turn red
   5. resume the current (suspended) thread — in Threads tab: context menu of the thread: "Resume Thread"
   6. now on the CPU tab you can see the real name of the `d3d9.dll`'s function being called: `qword [rax+3C8]=<d3d9.public: virtual long __cdecl CBaseDevice::PresentEx(…) __ptr64>`
      i.e. the call stack shown above looks like this:

      - 0, `ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa`
      - 1, `KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9c`
      - 2, `d3d9.dll!CBaseDevice::AcquireWriteAccess`
      - 3, `d3d9.dll!CBaseDevice::UpdateRenderTarget`
      - 4, `d3d9.dll!CD3DBase::SetRenderTargetI`
      - 5, `d3d9.dll!CSwapChain::ResetRenderTargets`
      - 6, `d3d9.dll!CSwapChain::PresentMain`
      - 7, `d3d9.dll!CBaseDevice::PresentMain`
      - 8, `d3d9.dll!CBaseDevice::PresentEx` ← [`PresentEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-idirect3ddevice9ex-presentex) ← [`Present`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-idirect3ddevice9-presen) — `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` wants to <del>present</del> show something to us…
      - 9, `LogiOptionsMgr.exe+0xd4343`
      - …
4. if you walk through this part of the program in the ["Step over" mode <kbd>F8</kbd>](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/menus/Debug.html#step-over), you can realize that this thread is spinning in a loop that begins with `movzx eax,byte ptr ds:[rsi+38]` (almost immediately after `call qword ptr ds:[<&NtUserShowWindow>]` <sup>[`ShowWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow)</sup>) and returns to the beginning after [`call qword ptr ds:[<&PeekMessageW>]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew)

At the beginning of the loop is the entry/end condition of the loop:

```x86asm
test al,al
jne logioptionsmgr.13F904520
```

If you replace [`jne`](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) [with](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc#description) [`je`](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html):

1. context menu: Assemble <kbd>space</kbd>
2. replace `jne` with `je`

… and resume execution <kbd>F9</kbd> of the program then the resources created by [`CoInitialize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize) and [`Direct3DCreate9Ex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-direct3dcreate9ex) (see above in the asm) will be properly released, the thread will exit, and the following records will appear on the Log tab (in case of GPU from NVIDIA):

```
DLL Unloaded: … nvd3dumx.dll
DLL Unloaded: … psapi.dll
Thread … exit
```

**Note:** unloading [`psapi.dll`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/process-status-helper) may have hinted that the personal mouse settings for applications will stop working (switching), however, the personal settings still work.

Before finally committing the patch, it remains to ensure that it works correctly when `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` is launched:

1. pre‑preparation:

   1. save the patch — in CPU tab: context menu of the asm view: Patches <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>: Export button; in my case (for v3.20.35), I got the following contents of the patch file `LogiOptionsMgr.1337`:

      ```
      >logioptionsmgr.exe
      00000000000D4317:85->84
      ```
   2. set a breakpoint on the `call qword ptr ds:[<&NtUserShowWindow>]` (was mentioned above)
2. preparation:

   1. restart the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` — Debug menu > Restart <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
   2. after the restart, the program execution should have stopped at the `call qword ptr ds:[<&NtUserShowWindow>]`, and as you can see, the patch (`jne` → `je`) was not applied automatically, so apply it manually — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>: Import button
3. [check](https://github.com/lornix/fenris/tree/59ad037f26#readme) the code execution path (the loop must be skipped) — "Step over" <kbd>F8</kbd> (or ["Animate over"](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/menus/Debug.html#animate-over), or use [tracing](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/views/Trace.html))
4. resume execution of the program — "Run" <kbd>F9</kbd>; the code execution path must be repeated again:

   - resources will be released
   - thread will terminate (exit)
   - the corresponding records will appear on the Log tab

To commit the patch, open the "Patches" dialog <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again: "Patch File" button (temporarily save the patched `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` to another location, and then replace the original one).

Don't forget to detach the debugger (File menu > [Detach](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/menus/File.html#detach)), or immediately terminate the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` process (Debug menu > [Close <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/menus/Debug.html#close)) prior to replacing the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` file.

**Note:** during the above, minidumps `minidump\dump-*_*.dmp` could appear in the directory with the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe` — it is safe to delete them.

**Note:** in the general case, after replacing the `LogiOptionsMgr.exe`, it is better to restart its parent (`LogiOptions.exe`) by logoff <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> / login.